# Compute column by function COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function

I have a table "Student_Records" consisting of the columns "StudentID", "Finished Course" and "Credits". From here on i want to compute the value in the column "Credits" by getting the COUNT from the column "Finished Course" for that specific "StudentID".

How do i compute the column "Credits"?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output.

Comment: Yes, most similiar cases i saw "user-defined functions" which i didnt succed to understand.

Comment: @user2165793: It is hard to tell what you want without seeing some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If FinishedCourse is just flag value like 1 or 0 which indicates course is completed or not and one student have multiple records for finished courses then you can update Credit column like below :

```
UPDATE      [Student_Records]
SET         [Credits]   = (SELECT SUM(FinishedCourse) AS Credits FROM Student_Records WHERE StudentID = SR.StudentID)
FROM        [dbo].[Student_Records] SR
```